# When using YUI TaskNode, when clicking on labels, my listener on labelClick isn't called?

Tags: tree, yui

How come when using a YUI tree using `TaskNode` (illustrated below) my listener on `labelClick` isn't called, while it is called if I create the same tree with `TextNode`?

[image: YUI tree with TaskNode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely something that used to work. The [YUI code](https://github.com/yui/yui2/blob/839d9a06eacdd4151e41956b81d47c73354fc3dc/sandbox/treeview/js/TaskNode.js#L278) in `TaskNode.js` calls `TextNode.onLabelClick()` which [does just](https://github.com/yui/yui2/blob/e1130a4d8d723f9f184a2248420c6400c3b31362/src/treeview/js/TextNode.js#L179) a `return false`. This will work if you modify `TaskNode.js` and instead of calling `node.labelClick(node)`, call `tree.fireEvent('labelClick', node)`. Specifically, replace:

```
sb[sb.length] = ' onclick="return ' + getNode + '.onLabelClick(' + getNode +')"';
```

With:

```
sb[sb.length] = ' onclick="' + getNode + '.tree.fireEvent(\'labelClick\',' + getNode +'); return false;"';
```